# game development - making maps

Tags: java, android, c++, ios

I have a generic question about making maps when developing a game. So it looks like most maps are larger than the screen size, and as you move around new areas are either revealed or dynamically rendered as you reach them. My question is, how are these maps created? I'm doing some iOS development and might want to do some RPG related work in the future but I'm not sure how to go about creating a larger than screen size map.

so basically what's confusing me is for example... when someone is creating a large map, do they see the whole thing and place objects where they want or do they have to guesstimate where something goes and programmatically assign x/y (and maybe z) coordinates to it? see what I'm trying to ask?

Very interested in this, eagerly awaiting responses!

Comment: See the related discussion here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58760/how-to-handle-a-tile-map-scrolling

Comment: This question is better migrated to Game Development site in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most RPG (and many other) games with a map like the one you're talking about, the game engine uses a [tile map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile_engine). Depending on the size of the map, there is the choice of having the entire tile map within memory, or have it split up into sections which are then loaded on the fly from files (like [chunks](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunks) in MineCraft). Either way, it's more common to see more tiles loaded in memory than are visible on screen. The engine must determine which of these tiles will be drawn at the moment, and only draw those.

The person working on designing the map or levels usually uses a level editor tool that can either zoom in/out to see more tiles or can easily scroll through the tiles to edit them.

Comment: i like your explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

Typically in game design a full map is created, larger than the screen, and then only part is shown. That way, behavior can be established to move the viewing window under certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In the iOS world you would use something like a `UIScrollView` or a `MKMapView`. Take a look at the documentation for those to get an idea how you might implement this and what the costs are:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone in their right mind would hard-code maps (apart from POCs).
Either they code some facility to load a map from a text file (good for tile-based games), and they create it in their favorite text editor ; or they roll out a level editor, where they can zoom in and out and fly around freely, placing things (think Minecraft's creative mode).
A level editor is relatively long to make, but after you sank some time up front to get it working, your level building speed is considerably enhanced.